# Наследование и конструкторы базовых классов

Tags: c#

Итак учитывая свои предыдущие ошибки в расположении вопроса я задам его в самом начале: Для чего конструктору производного класса вызывать конструктор базового?
Для себя я уяснил это таким образом это так: поскольку поля класса рекомендуется скрывать, то для того чтобы корректно инициализировать  базовую часть объекта(те поля что были унаследованы), нам собственно и нужен вызов того самого базового конструктора поскольку он имеет доступ к тем самым скрытым полям. Хотелось бы узнать  может есть ещё какая-то причина кроме этой.

Comment: Чтобы создать/присвоить поля, объявленные на соответствующем уровне иерархии.

Comment: Сам объект создать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы описываете класс, вы можете указать в нем поля, свойства, события, методы и прочие вещи, и у каждой их таких вещей есть своё назначение. 
Назначением конструктора является указание логики, которая должна выполниться при создании экземпляра класса. 
То есть, вот есть класс. Экземпляр этого класса можно создавать кодом или создавать через рефлексию или наследовать от класса другой класс и создавать экземпляр наследника - классу все равно, как его создали, ему только важно то, что если программист указал в конструкторе логику, то она в любом случае должна отработать при создании класса. 
Поглядим на первый пример, где будет неявный вызов конструктора базового класса.

```
class Base 
{
    public Base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

class D : Base{ }
```

У нас есть 2 класса. Базовый и наследник. Человек, что описал базовый класс, указал определенную логику для создания класса (`Console.WriteLine("Base");`). Эта логика должна выполниться в любом случае, когда создается экземпляр. Например:

```
var b = new Base();
var d = new D();
var c = Activator.CreateInstance<Base>();
var e = Activator.CreateInstance<D>();
```

При любом из вариантов выше указанная логика `Console.WriteLine("Base");` отработает, так как так задумано создателем класса.

Мы сейчас рассматривали конструктор без параметров. Но что, если для создания класса, ему нужна дополнительная информация? Например

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }

    public Person(string name, string lastName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be empty!");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Last Name cannot be empty!");
        Name = name;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Поглядим на код. Так как у нас только 1 конструктор в классе, то, чтобы создать экземпляр нашего класса, обязательно надо предоставить ему имя и фамилию. Без этого класс, по задумке автора класса, работать не должен. Один этот конструктор гарантирует (для большинства случаев), что экземпляр класса никогда не будет создан без имени и фамилии. Причем самому классу не важно, что от него могут создавать наследников - требование имени и фамилии остается в силе. То есть вот это

```
class Developer : Person
{       
}
```

Просто не скомпилируется, так как нарушено требование класса `Person`- которое гласит, что если хочешь наследоваться от него, то будь добр предоставь мне имя и фамилию. Сделать это можно двумя способами. Например, просто захардкодить

```
class Developer : Person
{
    public Developer() : base("Vasya","Pupkin")
    {           
    }
}
```

В этом случае, вы сможете создавать девелоперов так

```
var developer = new Developer();
```

Но все они будут Васями Пупкиными. Скорее всего, это не то, что следует делать. Обычно, конструкторы классов-наследников имеют те же параметры, что и конструкторы базовых классов, плюс ещё что то. Например:

```
class Developer : Person
{
    public string Specialization { get; }

    public Developer(string name, string lastName, string specialization)
        : base(name, lastName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(specialization))
            throw new ArgumentException("Specialization cannot be empty!");
        Specialization = specialization;
    }
}
```

Теперь при создании девелопера придется указывать всё, что требуется - иначе никак

```
var developer = new Developer("Vasya", "Pupkin", "Frontend-guru");
```

Подводя итог, скажу, что вызывать конструкторы базовых классов необходимо, так как создатели тех классов на это и рассчитывают, и в таком случае эти базовые классы могут себя инициализировать должным образом, таким, как заложено автором класса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ tym, а подскажите как сделать такое же форматирование как у вас если конечно вы не из студии это взяли, в моём случаи ждать 1-2 мин для того чтобы открылась студи я весьма утомительно особенно в случаи если нужно просто что-то мелкое проверить. Dotnetfiddle единственное спасения для людей с ноутбуком.

Comment: @Mark на сайте используется обычная markdown разметка, вы её можете в любом редакторе написать, хоть в блокноте. Я для этого [обычно использую](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNg0P.png) [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), но если вам нужна тулза для форматирования и запуска фрагментов кода кода, могу посоветовать [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) или тот же VSCode, но он из коробки не форматирует.