# В конструкторе потомка нет параметров конструктора родителя

Tags: c#, ооп

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent(int a) { }
}
class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(string b) : base() 
    {
    }
}
```

Как решить эту проблему без создания в родителе конструктора с одним параметром string? base(int a) очевидно не работает.

Comment: Нужно передать в конструктор родителя какое-либо значение. Например: `base(5)`.

Comment: Без уточнения деталей - почему выбрана именно такая реализация классов - непонятно, что советовать. Ну передайте родителю 0, например: `base(0)`

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно следующее: `public Child(string b, int a) : base(a)`

Comment: связанный вопрос [Наследование и конструкторы базовых классов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/961800/179763)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не разрешима в текущих условиях (не понятно зачем родителю требуется int a)

Но в самом примитивном варианте:

```
class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(string b) : base(0) 
    {
    }
}
```

Родителю можно просто скормить в конструктор любое число)